# What is the source for 50 total episodes of Twin Star Exorcists?

Tags: twin-star-exorcists

So far there are 25 episodes aired. [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32105/Sousei_no_Onmyouji) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Star_Exorcists#Episode_list) claim there are supposed to be 50 episodes. What is the source for that number?

Answer (score 1):

I've searched for a bit and found out the only known source of that information is from a chinese anime streaming company iQIYI on [their listing page](http://www.iqiyi.com/a_19rrhaeqtd.html%20), as relayed by [this Crunchyroll news post](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/05/13-1/chinese-streaming-site-lists-twin-star-exorcists-and-ace-attorney-episode-counts).